# RewriteRule: move id article in url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to move the post id to the last position in the url. Like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/news/123-post.html
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.com/news/post-123.html
```

Original htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ index.php?newsid=$2&seourl=$3&seocat=$1 [L]
```

I change to

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?newsid=$2&seourl=$3&seocat=$1 [L]
```

and paste new url http://www.mysite.com/news/post-123.html in browser but it don't work

Comment: Can you show your complete .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have swapped `news id` and `seo url` parameters. You have to do the same in your rule.

This rule (the new one)

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?newsid=$2&seourl=$3&seocat=$1 [L]
```

should look like this

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?newsid=$3&seourl=$2&seocat=$1 [L]
```

`$2` is now into `seourl` and `$3` is now into `newsid`. Otherwise, you'll have a problem.

Also, you can optimize your rule by making sure `seourl` does not contain any slash (`/`) if you want it to be only in same folder and not an entier path

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([^/]+)-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?newsid=$3&seourl=$2&seocat=$1 [L]
```